# How to create User friendly URL in WordPress?

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to create a custom URL for all users to view user details.

My user information page URL is: `https://www.example.com/author/test_user`

I need to create a URL like this: `https://www.example.com/test_user`

Is it possible with WordPress?

Comment: (almost) everything is possible, what is the exact problem you have with implementing it yourself?

Comment: i don't know how to do this. Please guide me.

Comment: In your opinion, how does WordPress will distinguish between _post URL_ and _user URL_ in case of `example.com/test_user`?

Comment: In WordPress there's an option to set your URL or permalink just go to your settings page, then check permalinks, choose the permalink style that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution for this. Add this code to your theme's `functions.php`. After that you need to re-save your permalinks from `Settings->Permalinks` in WordPress dashboard.

```
function remove_author_base() {
/**
 * Remove Author base from Wp Links
 * Serkan Algur
 */
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = '';
}
add_action('init', 'remove_author_base', 1);
```

I tested this code on my localhost (apache server with htaccess enabled). Please comment if code works or not.